# Full functional dependencies

Tags: database-normalization

Alright I can't seem to wrap my head around the subject normalization.

I have this table
[image]

Now I need to find the full functional dependencies.

```
FilmID, Actor -> Title, Year, Director

Publisher -> PublisherCity

Actor -> DOB, Country
```

Now Can someone tell me if I'm on the right track? if not then any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Tables

  - fields

I hope this helps:

- films

  - id
  - title
  - year
  - director_id
  - publisher_id

*One publisher and director only with this setup.*

- actors

  - id
  - name
  - dob
  - country

*you missed name from Actor attrs*

- films_actors

  - film_id
  - actor_id

*This is a join table of films to actors. Allowing you to link limitless actors to films (Many to Many relationship).*

- publishers

  - id
  - name
  - city

*self explanatory*

- directors

  - id
  - name

*self explanatory*

any questions just ask.

Comment: Thanks alot, what normal form is that 3rd? But could you write like how you found the dependencies cuz thats what I'm having trouble doing like how do I know which columns are dependent on the composite key. Is it all simply logical like filmID->Title....etc or is there some pattern I have to follow.

Comment: Remember that directors and actors are both persons. Some actors have directed films that they acted in themselves ...

Comment: @joop - absolutely, although I'm not sure MizziPizzi is ready for polymorphic relationships yet ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking "how can I design" relationships, well one thing is practice and reading the right books. Here is a short cut ->find the `cardinality` of any relationship. 
For e.g. Consider books and author's. One author can write multiple books so the cardinality is multiple on the book side. This is called `one to many` relationship. Now with practice you learn that this can be modelled in a relational db using a foreign key. Like the `director_id` in films table of @Isotope's answer

Now consider that some books(for e.g. the professional series) can be written by multiple authors. Now cardinality is multiple on both sides of the relationship. This is known as `many to many` relationship. You can design this relationship using `film_actors` kind of mapping table from above answer. For basic modelling this much is more than enough. Do take a look at this excellent article on [infoq](http://www.infoq.com/articles/seven-modelling-smells) which might help you in this.

Comment: Well I'm already familiar with ER modelling but that link was very helpful :) I'm not really asking how to design relationships just how to identify full functional dependencies as I've started doing in my original post :)